# Why df.to_csv function writing the file as one big string per row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have searched a lot but could not find a solution to my problem.
Here is what i am trying to do:

1. Read multiple txt(csv) files into dataframes and merge them into one big data frame. They have identical columns! (no problem)
2. Now when I try to write the final (concatinated) dataframe back into txt(csv) file, the function to_csv writing the content per row as strings per row. I need it to be like a normal csv file which is comma separated (but not contained in string per row).

What Am I doing wrong? May be not using concat or append function correctly?

My code:

#### Reading csv files into dataframes and appending them into a list

```
dfs=[]

for f in filenames:

df = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter='\t',header=None)

dfs.append(df)
```

#### concat them into final dataframe

```
dfs=pd.concat(dfs,axis=0)
```

#### Writing the final dataframe into one txt(csv) file

```
dfs.to_csv('merged.txt',header=None,index=False)
```

Here is the problem, the first row of the merged.txt file looks like (only copying few values from single row):

```
"131118091409,-400.198565,-0.018061"
```

How can I write the file without the double quotes (strings) per row? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are your csv correctly read in the first place? You read with tab delimiter, but if it's a comma it's not going to work, and there will be strings in your dataframes. No wonder the strings are still here after you write the concatenated dataframe.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut yes everythig is correct until i try to write the file back to csv file (after concatination). My csv file is tab separated. The problem is only the strings in final file. I need to read the final file again. When i do so the data frame has only one column due to string.

Comment: You should check your dataframes (the ones you read, and the concatenated one). Pandas won't write a string if it's not a string. And I strongly suspect your input data is not tab separated.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I found the typo! when i tried to read the merged file back again (i mistakenly pass delimter tab) and when it does not find it it there, it somehow makes it a string :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

> df = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter='\t',header=None)

Remove the **delimiter='\t'** or use this instead:

> df = pd.read_csv(f,delimiter=',', header=None)